# SharePoint Designer - get custom proprty value from User Profile List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, user-profile-property

In SharePoint 2010 Designer - I can look-up "user Profile" list and get data from the properties.

I have created custom property "CustProp" in User Profile. Can i get the value of the custom property in the User Profile list using SPD 2010 ?

Comment: any ideas on how to do it?